# Problem with rendering object prop sent to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, usecallback

The problem is: Every time I click the button, I see "Button render" in the console. But I want to see this post only once
The problem is: Every time I click the button, I see "Button render" in the console. But I want to see this post only once

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
    import Button from "./Button";
    
    const UseCallback = () => {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    
      const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        setCount((prevState) => prevState + 1);
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{count}</p>
          <Button
            deneme={{ aaa: "aaa", bbb: "bbb" }}
            handleClick={handleClick}
          ></Button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
 export default UseCallback;


   
    import React from "react";
    
    const Button = ({ handleClick }) => {
      console.log("Button - rerender");
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Sayacı artır</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default React.memo(Button);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is suppose to re-render since the callback is changing on render and you are passing a new object reference on each render to button. You already have `React.memo` but since you have a new object reference every time it's a re-rendering button.

Try wrapping object in `useMemo` to keep the same reference or create a variable at top and pass it in `deneme`  prop

```
const UseCallback = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCount((prevState) => prevState + 1);
  }, []);
  const deneme = useMemo(() => {
    return { aaa: "aaa", bbb: "bbb" };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <Button deneme={deneme} handleClick={handleClick}></Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

or

```
const deneme = {
  aaa: "aaa",
  bbb: "bbb"
};
const UseCallback = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCount((prevState) => prevState + 1);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <Button handleClick={handleClick}></Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

So only thing you are missing is to pass a compareFunction which will tell [React.Memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) exact condition when to rerender the component. You can see your code working here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cherry-bv5y0?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";

const Button1 = ({ handleClick }) => {
  console.log("Button - rerender");
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Sayacı artır</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const compareFunction = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return true; //As props only have a function which we are sure doesn't change.
};

const Button = React.memo(Button1, compareFunction);

const UseCallback = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCount((prevState) => prevState + 1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <Button
        deneme={{ aaa: "aaa", bbb: "bbb" }}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      ></Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UseCallback;
```